# Canon i560-Paper size error-with printer driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, printing, canon

just upgraded from 11.10 and been using Ubuntu since 9.04. The Canon driver in 11.10 worked OK with A4 paper, but it looks to me as if it prints to A5 size when you select A4 in Ubuntu 12.04.

To amplify, selecting A4 paper and 'fit to page' gives a print preview which is correctly sized and as expected, but when it commits to paper, the print area is half size.

Answer (score 2):

## Issue fixed in updated CUPS drivers.

If not try this:

- go to System Settings -> Printing
- right click the printer and select properties
- In Settings click the change button next to Make and Model
- select "select printer from database" and choose "Canon (recommended)" and click Forward
- Then select i850 (the option below the recommended one) and click forward
- Select "Use the new PPD as is" option and press apply

That did the trick with me.